# how to stop while loop used in function?

Tags: python, function, while-loop

in this piece of code the program is asking to enter the password,password must have at least 8 char and with numbers and letters,if any of these condition did not meet so the program give warning and ask again to enter the password! so when the password is met the condition ,the loop does not stop and ask again!!
I'd like to know how can I stop it when the password is correct?

```
def passValidation(password):

   if len(password) < 8 :
     print('ur password must be at least 8 char :')
   elif password.isnumeric():
     print('ur password must have one letter')
   elif password.isalpha():
     print('ur password must have one number')
   else :     
     print('ur password is true')
    
while True :
  password = input('enter ur password:')     
  passValidation(password)
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: Nothing in you code says or tests if the password is correct. That should be the next thing to introduce.

Comment: @cow testing the text messages returned by a function is a bad idea and a maintenance nightmare to come - what when you change the message, the language... The function should return one essential information: is the password correct, or not. So, a boolean.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille You're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fine for your `passValidation` to print out useful statements indicating how the password is invalid, but ultimately it should `return` `True` or `False` to indicate password validity.

Second, you don't necessarily have to enter into a loop if the first input password is fine in the first place. Instead of immediately jumping into a while loop, prompt for a password then enter into the loop if it's invalid. This makes it clearer what your `while` condition should be rather than using `while True` with a `break` statement.

```
def passValidation(password):
    if len(password) < 8 :
        print('ur password must be at least 8 char :')
        return False
    elif password.isnumeric():
        print('ur password must have one letter')
        return False
    elif password.isalpha():
        print('ur password must have one number')
        return False
    else:     
        print('ur password is true')
        return True

password = input('enter ur password:')

while not passValidation(password):
    password = input('enter ur password:')
```